# Выполнение playbook под конфигурацию mikrotik

Tags: python, linux, debian, ansible, ansible-playbook

Возникла следующая проблема. При воде значений которые записываются в переменные которые прописаны в playbook выдает данную ошибку не могу понять как ее устранить и что написано не так

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

файл hosts в котором прописано подключение

```
[mikrotik_ovpn_pki]
test1 ansible_ssh_port=22 ansible_ssh_user=admin ansible_ssh_host=11.11.11.11
```

файл playbook

```
---
- hosts: all
  become: true
  vars:
   ssh_user: admin

  vars_prompt:
  - name: ssh_ip
    prompt: "Введите ip устройства для доступа к нему"
    private: no
  - name: name
    prompt: "Введите имя устройства"
    private: no
  - name: iplan
    prompt: "Внутрений адрес устройства без последнего октета например: 666.666.6"
    private: no
  - name: akt
    prompt: "Введите последний актет ip адреса например: 66"
    private: no
  - name: nic
    prompt: "Введите name точки например: ap666"
    private: no

  tasks:
  - name: "generate client script from template"
    template: scr=templates/mikrotik_def_conf1.j2 dest=template_configs/mikrotik_def_conf1_{{ name }}.rsc backup=no
    tags: generate
  - name: "copy sert on client dev"
    command: "scp -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no template_configs/mikrotik_def_confl_{{ name }}.rsc {{ ssh_user }}@{{ ssh_ip }}:"
    tags: import
  - name: "import script on client device"
    command: ssh -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no {{ ssh_user }}@{{ ssh_ip }} "/import mikrotik_def_conf1_{{ name }}.rsc"
    tags: import
```

Comment: Ну так там написано, что на хосте чё-то не могут найти интерпритатор питона. Ты его туда ставил? Он вообще туда может установиться? Может юзать `raw`?

Comment: Поменяй картинку на текст.

Comment: замени scp на rsync

Comment: @eri, а в микроте есть рсинк? О_о

Comment: @donRumata зучем он там?

Comment: @eri, ну я хз зачем он там. Но раз ты советуешь поменять на rsync, то значит он там есть. Вот я и спрашивал

Comment: @donRumata `The ':' usages connect via remote shell`, он работает по ссх

Comment: Да, ssh - это способ подключения. А на той стороне что? В классическом линуксе на той тачке, куда цепляется ansible - должен быть питон, чтобы код выполнялся. Если там питона нет, то его или надо поставить или явно сказать ансиблу, что питона там нет и юзать его не надо от слова "совсем".

Comment: ансибл просто выполняет команды на  локальном устройстве. питон на роутере не нужен.

Comment: есть разные модули управления - какие-то требуют питон, какие-то нет. тут дело не в питоне. таск должен через модуль script а не через command

Comment: @donRumata да ты прав, питон тут тоже замешан

Comment: Питон замешан, когда ансибл собирает инфу о тачке. Все эти `ansible_hostname`, `ansible_env` и вот это всё.

Answer (score 0):

Таск такой должен через модуль script а не через command.

модуль command выполняет команду на целевом хосте - там стоит написать "/import mikrotik_def_conf1_{{ name }}.rsc" без ssh, потому что ансибл уже подключился, но она запускается напрямую без шела - не уверен что микротик примет её.

модуль [shell](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/shell_module.html#shell-module) может сработать там где не пойдет command

модуль [script](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/script_module.html#script-module) выполняет команду на хосте ансибла - тут команда пишется с ssh, scp, rsync и прочим

модуль [template](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/template_module.html#template-module) сам может копировать шаблон, scp наверное лишний

Comment: Не уверен на счёт `shell` и `script`. Но уверен на счёт `raw`. Я им докидываю питон на совсем уж голые тачки. `raw: test -e /usr/bin/python || test -e /usr/bin/apt-get && apt-get -y install python-minimal python-apt`

Answer (score 0):

Во-первых, Ansible ругается, что вы используете зарезервированное имя name в качестве имени переменной.

Во-вторых, Ansible вызывает специальный модуль setup перед выполнением первой таски. Модуль setup пытается приконнектиться к mikrotik-хост чтобы собрать факты (информацию) о хосте: IP адрес, дисковое пространство, архитектура процессора и т.д. Но это заканчивается неудачей, так как необходимо наличие интерпретатора python на mikrotik-хосте, которого там нет. Аналогично ругается на команды sftp, scp.

Вам поможет вот это:

gather_facts: false

И далее использовать для загрузки файла на mikrotik :

ansible_connection: network_cli

ansible_network_os: routeros

tasks:

```
- name: file upload

  net_put:

    src: ./file_script.rsc

    protocol: sftp
```

Версия Ansible должна быть >=2.6